# how to dynamically hide/show navBar in ionic framework?

Tags: ionic-framework

What I am trying do is hide ion-nav-bar when screen is in landscape because it will then take too much space. The ideal is set it css and this works very well on android devices but not on iOS devices.

There seems to be a bug in ionic that when ion-nav-bar is set to "display:none" some blank space will still be shown on iOS devices but not on android. I described the issue here:

http://forum.ionicframework.com/t/trouble-hiding-ion-nav-bar-on-ios-devices-but-not-android/31370

I am trying to figure out a way to get around this. The options are:

1) Use $ionicNavBarDelegate.showBar(false) on screen orientation change. This does hide the nav-bar but I am having trouble restore the navBar when screen is back in portrait mode.

2) Put hide-nav-bar="{{$root.hideNavBar}}" in ion-view then change the value of $root.hideNavBar on screen orientation change.

This seems not work. nav-bar shows/hides itself and don't act according the latest value of $root.hideNavBa.

Sorry I am a beginner, so please forgive my ignorance and advice.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

try to use ng-if for me it works with a heder

Comment: This seems not work on my hands. It acts according the initial value of the switch "hideNavBar" but not the latest. It also somehow hides nav-buttons inside nav-bar.